# Approximate any point of the interval $[-1/2,1/2]$ by the sum of $n$ iid uniform random variables from $[-1,1]$

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-concentration, geometric-probability

Let $x \in [-1/2,1/2]$ and $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be drawn iid from the uniform distribution on $[-1,1]$.

> **Question.** Given $\varepsilon \ge 0$ an integer $k \in [1,n]$, what is a good lower-bound on the probability $p_{n,k,\varepsilon}$ that: for every $x \in [-1/2,1/2]$, there exists $S \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ with $1 \le card(S) \le k$  such that  $|\sum_{i \in S} X_i-x| \le \varepsilon$ ?

I'm particularly interested in the case $k=n$.

**Notes.**

- If one could get a good lower-bound for the probability of approximating a fixed $x \in [-1/2,1/2]$ as a sum $\sum_{i \in S}X_i$, then one could use a covering argument on the interval $[-1/2,1/2]$ to get a uniform bound.

---

One could generalize the above problem as follows. Let $0 \le r < 1$ and $B_r^m$ be the origin-centered ball of radius $r$ in $\mathbb R^m$, and let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be drawn iid uniformly from the unit ball $B_1^m$.

> **Question.** What is a good lower-lower bound for the probability $p_{m,r,n,k,\varepsilon}$ that:
> for every $x \in B_r^m$, there exists $S \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ with $1 \le card(S) \le k$  such that  $\|\sum_{i \in S} X_i-x\| \le \varepsilon$ ?

As before, I'm particularly interested in the case $k=n$.

Comment: What sort of dependence does $\varepsilon$ have on $n$?  [If $n \varepsilon$ is bounded, this is going to be much different than the case where say $\varepsilon n > 10 \log(n)$.]

Comment: You may assume $\varepsilon \ge e^{-Cn}$, for some fixed constant $C>0$, independent of $n$.

Comment: Naturally, we'd need $\varepsilon > 2^{-n}$ or there won't be enough different sums to land in the $1/\varepsilon$ intervals needed.  Can we assume $\varepsilon > e^{-n/100}$ if we feel like?  Otherwise, if we have no control over $C$, then $\varepsilon$ might be much too small for this to be possible.

Comment: Take $C=  1/100$ if you like.

Comment: Even still, you're cutting it kind of close!  :-)  What kind of lower bound would you be happy with?  Anything that converges to 1?

Comment: I'm interested with how far one can go with the given data. Obviously, the tighter the bound, the better. One bound is not as good as another...